# Filter Entities with date of today?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

This is what I tried:

```
    $time = date('Y/m/d');
    $alerts = $repository->findBy(['datum' => $time]);
```

and

```
    $time = date('Y/m/d');
    $lessons = $repository->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->where('q.datum LIKE currentDate')
        ->setParameter('currentDate', $time);
```

[image]

For some reason those don't work and I have no idea why. It should be displaying the last one in a dd($lessons), but it doesn't

Update:

This is what I got rn, but it's still not working:

```
    $today = new \DateTime('today');
    $tomorrow = new \DateTime('today +1 day');

    $lessons = $repository->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->where('q.datum > :today')
        ->andWhere('q.datum < :tomorrow')
        ->setParameter('today', $today)
        ->setParameter('tomorrow', $tomorrow);
```

Comment: `q.date LIKE currentDate` should be `q.datum = :currentDate`. Have you enabled dev mode?

Comment: Variable Naming: It helps if they make sense for their contents, so if you are collecting a date call it something like `$date` and not `$time`

Comment: AS MySQL likes its dates formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` try `$time = date('Y-m-d');`

Comment: For what it's worth, using `/` as date separator triggers a warning but is accepted anyway. (Of course, no reason to do it wrong in the first place, it's the same exact amount of work).

Comment: You're told you have a couple of typos and you produce a completely different code snippet, and it seems you still don't see error messages. No offence, but I suspect you're copypasting code from ChatGPT or a similar source that you don't really understand, and you're seemingly running Symfony in prod environment with debug disabled, or you'd be getting comprehensive error pages. With that approach, it'll take years to complete your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the current database date function to perform this query? It would look like this:

```
$lessons = $repository->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->where('q.datum > now()')
        ->andWhere('q.datum < now()+ INTERVAL 1 DAY');
```

Comment: Doesn't `QueryBuilder` expect DQL rather than SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Your checking the date format 'Y/m/d' (2023/05/11) with a saved date field format in the database 'Y-m-d' (2023-05-11)

Besides that your checking if you can find the current date but according to your database table there is no current date.

The other check that your doing is checking if there is a date higher then 2023-05-11 00:00:00, you should change this to higher and the same '>='

Answer (score 0):

i guess your entity date field is a datetime field (or at least a date field), when not, make sure it is, then you need to use the DateTime Object for searching

your entity field should look like this

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $datum;

# [...]

public function getDatum(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->datum;
}

public function setDatum(\DateTimeInterface $datum): self
{
    $this->datum = $datum;

    return $this;
}
```

your repo function can be look like this

```
// src/Repository/TableRepository.php
public function findByStartAndEndDate($dateStart, $dateEnd)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');

    return $qb
        ->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->between('q.datum', ':dateStart', ':dateEnd')
        )
        ->setParameter('dateStart', $dateStart)
        ->setParameter('dateEnd', $dateEnd)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

using that funcion inside your controller

```
// src/Controller/TableController.php
$dateStart = new DateTime();
$dateEnd = new DateTime('+1 days');

$items = $repository->findByStartAndEndDate($dateStart, $dateEnd);
```

gl hf